# how to reference the public schema of jasperserver database in the context.xml file?

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, war, jasperserver, meta-inf

I am trying to get the Jasperserver community edition running on tomcat. I am following steps from the documentation after a successful build using the install scripts from buildomatic, I try and run tomcat server but it complains about 'relation jiresourcefolder does not exist'. Upon checking the database all the required tables are loaded under jasperserver database public schema.

IN the context.xml  found under (jasperserver/META-INF) the correct database is referenced. Does anyone know how to refer the public sh=chema so that all the required tables are accessible or is there any other configuration needed that I missed?

Comment: show us the contents of the file (context.xml) and tell us the name of the database you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right you have to change the url from:

```
url="jdbc:postgresql://166.78.177.147:8082/jasperserver"
```

to

```
url="jdbc:postgresql://166.78.177.147:8082/public"
```